# Add days and create a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a function from an API call which get's the date.
To be precise, what I am doing is I am attempting to grab this field, e.g

17/05/2022, which is in my app as:

```
{new Date(job.created).toLocaleDateString()}
```

However, what I would like to do is basically take the above and minus 5 days. If the date is greater than that difference, then just tag an h1 saying old

I have the following code working, and logging out my dates correctly:

```
  const fiveDaysAgo = new Date(today - (5*days)).toLocaleDateString()
  const datePosted = new Date(job.created).toLocaleDateString()

  console.log('five days ago is', fiveDaysAgo)
  console.log('date posted was', datePosted)
```

However I would like to conditionally render, such as -

```
  { fiveDaysAgo < datePosted
          <Typography>
            New!
          </Typography>
          }
```

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: You can deduce 5 using the following method before converting to localeDateString

```fiveDaysAgo.setDate(fiveDaysAgo.getDate() - 5)```

Your comparison seems to be fine except you would have to use correct conditional rendering with ```condition ? true : false```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const fiveDaysAgo = new Date(today - (5*days)).toLocaleDateString()
  const datePosted = new Date(job.created).toLocaleDateString()

  console.log('five days ago is', fiveDaysAgo)
  console.log('date posted was', datePosted)

//then compare timestamp

fiveDaysAgo = fiveDaysAgo.getTime();
datePosted = datePosted.getTime();

{ fiveDaysAgo < datePosted
          <Typography>
            New!
          </Typography>
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a function to convert value in a desired way. In this case you transform `snake_case` to `Capitalised Text` values.

```
const days = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

const isOutdated = (date: Date): boolean => {
  const nowStamp = new Date().getTime();
  const dateStamp = date.getDate();
  return nowStamp - dateStamp > 5 * days;
};
```

Then you are free to use it as any other JS code inside of JSX return:

```
const Component = ({ createdAt }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {!isOutdated(createdAt) && (
        <Typography>
          New!
        </Typography>  
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).